# Using a setter to inform the user if they've entered valid data

Tags: c#, console-application

At the moment the setter is working, however its not informing the user straight after they enter invalid data. Once a user has been created it will get saved to a Json file. This is where the error is shown, which is not what I want. I was thinking of throwing an exception in the setter, and then adding another catch in the AddPatient procedure? I'm a bit curious as to whether that would be good/bad.

```
    }
    private string gender;
    public string UserGender
    {
        get 
        {
            return gender;
        }
        set 
        {
            if (value != "m" || value != "f")
            {                    
                Console.Write("Error: Please enter m or f: ");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your procedure does not invoke PatientGender property. It would be much better for readability if you can provide a bit more code snippets of your class.

Comment: apologies, Ive pasted more of the code from the Patient class is that more helpful?

Answer (score 1):

The properties in C# are responsible mostly for the encapsulation of data and It is good approach to make them as simpler as possible. Please, read about single responsibility principle.

What I suggest, in case you do want to add some validation rule to your property PatientGender, is to let the property only be responsible of correctness of your input and do not put some reading data logic part there.
Here is a simple example how you can do it, just by adjusting your code:

```
    public string PatientGender
    {
        get { return gender; }
        set
        {
            if (value == "male" || value == "female")
            {
                gender = value;
            }
            else
            {
                // As it was noted in the comment, we should notify the caller that the validation has failed
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input");
                // or throw an exception here
            }
        }
    }
```

In your Patient class you can add the procedure which will read the user input and validate the input value until the moment it is correct:

```
public Patient ReadAndValidatePatientGender(Patient patient)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input.Equals("male", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || input.Equals("female", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            patient.PatientGender = input;
            return patient;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your main procedure, where you create your Patient class object, you will invoke the ReadAndValidatePatientGender procedure:

```
currentPatinet = ReadAndValidatePatientGender(currentPatient);
```

Comment: Selectively choosing to set a value only if it's valid is not a good approach IMHO. The caller will never know that their action did noting unless they explicitly call the getter afterwards.

Comment: @Xerillio Yes, totally agree with your note. Does it mean, in case we add some validation  into the setter, when validation actually fails we always should notify about it?

Comment: @Xerillio I have updated my answer considering your comment, thanks a lot.

Comment: @OmelianLevkovych: using console IO as notification of an invalid value is not a good approach imo. You should throw an exception which can be caught and handled wherever that makes sense (e.g. in the userinterface).

Comment: @JohanDonne Yea I totally agree with you and that is why I have also left the comment under the console output there. However, I have chosen the console IO here to make it more clear for the author of the question. The code I have provided is mostly a snippets of ideas what he can do to fix his problem. Anyway thanks for making it more clear.

Comment: @OmelianLevkovych I would avoid "side effects" whenever possible (such as writing to console, throwing an exception). My recommendation would be to use a type for the property that ensures you cannot give invalid input.

Comment: @Xerillio Can you provide some code snippet or write a bit more, what exactly you mean by - use a type for the property to ensure that you can not give invalid input?

Comment: @OmelianLevkovych I've given my suggestion in an answer now :)

Comment: Damn thanks guys! this has been a massive help to me! :)

Comment: @Xerillio Thanks, definitely looks much better. Sometimes, it is just hard enough to answer simple question without adding too much complexity for the person who created the question. However, I totally agree that my answer is too far from ideal, and I should done it the right way from the start. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a good design of your class/properties you should think about making it as easy to understand and use from a "callers" perspective. That means, if you have some specific requirements about which input a property should allow, then try to use a type that ensures the caller cannot use the property incorrectly.

I don't know how new you are to C#, so you may want to look into what an [`enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) is. In this case I would introduce an enum `Gender`:

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female,
    Other
}
```

Your property should then have `Gender` as its type:

```
private Gender gender;
public Gender PatientGender
{
    get 
    {
        return gender;
    }
    set 
    {
        this.gender = value;
    }
}
```

Now, it's easy to understand all the possible values that the property allows. If you want to be able to convert a string into this enum, you can add a helper method:

```
public static Gender ConvertToGender(string genderString)
{
    var genderLowercase = genderString.ToLower();
    switch (genderLowercase)
    {
        case "male":
            return Gender.Male;
        case "female":
            return Gender.Female;
        default:
            return Gender.Other;
    }
}
```

(alternatively throw an exception instead of returning `Gender.Other`)